# Function to search for specific number and then to further search for the prefix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a huge amount of data to process in which 4 points with a related prefix needs to be subtracted from each other.
Data consists of ID and x value

Example
ID = 290.12, 290.03, 290.06, 290.09, 300.12, 300.03, 300.06, 300.09, 301.12, 301.03, 301.06, 301.09
(let's call prefix a "ring number" and suffix time on the clock)
X value = any numerical value for each ID assigned

What I'm hoping to do is to search for the first number before the dot i.e. 300 and then subtract the value of 300.06-300.12 in one cell and in another cell 300.03-300.09.

(The subtraction is just an example, how I need to manipulate with the numbers is slightly more complicated, but I got this one under control)

This is my actual [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40N74.jpg) and what I need to produce is to the right of the raw data. At the moment, I'm doing it manually for each set of "rings"

Anyone knows how to approach this? I'm thinking vlookup, but I'm not very proficient in excel.

[New Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6k4C.jpg)

I tried vlookup, but I don't know how to construct the formula and I run out of ideas.

Comment: `=IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:A13,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(b,"."),"")))),1),"")` this will produce a spill range of the ring number in the first column and the x value on the second. You can than easily use this to (V)lookup your value.

Comment: All learning is very much appreciated but, as hard as I try, I really don't understand this one. Not even sure what cell/s should it go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I found out that `REDUCE` is no requirement in this case, so it can be shortened to:

```
=SQRT(SUM(((INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(I3+0.09,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3))-INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(I3+0.03,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3)))^2)))
```

You could change `+0.09` and `+0.03` to your needs and may reference them using LET() for easy maintaining:

```
=LET(id,I3, 
     _id1,0.09,
     _id2,0.03,
SQRT(SUM(((INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id1,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3))-INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id2,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3)))^2))))
```

Previous answer:

```
=LET(
 id,I3,
_id1,0.09,
_id2,0.03,
SQRT(
     REDUCE(0, SEQUENCE(1,3),
     LAMBDA(x, y,
     x+((INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id1,A:A),y)
     -INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id2,A:A),y))
     ^2)))))
```

This formula looks for the matching value of the id value `I3` + `_id1` minus the matching value of id value + `_id2` for columns B to D and adds the ^2 results per column. Then it calculates it's square root.

You can change `_id1` and `_id2` to your needs.

[image]

To calculate the Delta (as shown) at once you could use:

```
=LET(id,I3,
     _id1,0.09,
     _id2,0.03,
     _id3,0.12,
     _id4,0.06,
     x,SQRT(SUM((INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id1,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3))-INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id2,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3)))^2)),
     y,SQRT(SUM((INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id3,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3))-INDEX(B:D,XMATCH(id+_id4,A:A),SEQUENCE(1,3)))^2)),
(x-y)*1000)
```

You can have a column of unique values of the integers and a new column where you reference these values as `id` and drag down the formula to get your row by row result

In another column you can refer to these columns and sort per the second column using SORTBY()

Comment: Thank you, but what is r in this equation?

Comment: The `r` is to reference the range mentioned in the BYROW function; `ids` in this case. Renaming it `r` within the BYROW/LAMBDA makes `r` be a row by row reference to `ids`.